# How to mock jdbc connection and resultSet using Mockito in TestNG

Tags: java, unit-testing, jdbc, mockito, resultset

I have to write some unit tests but I have problem with mocking `ResultSet` and jdbc `Connection`.

I have this method:

```
@Test
public void test3() throws SQLException, IOException {

    Connection jdbcConnection = Mockito.mock(Connection.class);
    ResultSet resultSet = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);

    Mockito.when(resultSet.next()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
    Mockito.when(resultSet.getString(1)).thenReturn("table_r3").thenReturn("table_r1").thenReturn("table_r2");
    Mockito.when(jdbcConnection
            .createStatement()
            .executeQuery("SELECT name FROM tables"))
            .thenReturn(resultSet);

    //when
    List<String> nameOfTablesList = null;
    try {
        nameOfTablesList = Helper.getTablesName(jdbcConnection);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //then
    Assert.assertEquals(nameOfTablesList.size(), 3);
}
```

And error is showing in line `executeQuery("SELECT name FROM tables")` and it sounds like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException HelperTest.test3(HelperTest.java:71)
```

Any ideas whats going wrong?

Comment: You might want to consider not mocking the database connection, but either isolate the database behind an API so you can mock that API, or use an in-memory database.

Comment: BTW: Your test suggests that `Helper.getTablesName` does what [`DatabaseMetaData.getTables`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getTables-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-) is for

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to create an *expectation* on `jdbcConnection.createStatement()`.

By default, I believe a `null` is returned.

Should read something like:

```
ResultSet resultSet = Mockito.mock(ResultSet.class);
Mockito.when(resultSet.next()).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(true).thenReturn(false);
Mockito.when(resultSet.getString(1)).thenReturn("table_r3").thenReturn("table_r1").thenReturn("table_r2");

Statement statement = Mockito.mock(Statement.class);
Mockito.when(statement.executeQuery("SELECT name FROM tables")).thenReturn(resultSet);

Connection jdbcConnection = Mockito.mock(Connection.class);
Mockito.when(jdbcConnection.createStatement()).thenReturn(statement);
```

Comment: thanks, I was thinking about this but I didn't know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Mocking the JDBC API on this low level is rather tedious as you should really look into mocking the entirety of the JDBC API. Just a few examples:

- What would happen if anyone called `ResultSet.previous()`?
- What would happen if anyone called `ResultSet.getObject()` rather than `getString()`?
- What would happen if the `ResultSet` was obtained through `Statement.getResultSet()`?

To your client code, it shouldn't matter much if you're calling JDBC one way or another, the result should always be the same. If you really *have to* mock the database (rather than use e.g. a test database, or better, a [testcontainers based approach](https://www.testcontainers.org/)), then using something like jOOQ's [`MockDataProvider`](https://blog.jooq.org/2013/02/20/easy-mocking-of-your-database/) or [`MockFileDatabase`](https://blog.jooq.org/2018/04/10/mocking-jdbc-using-a-set-of-sql-string-result-pairs/) would certainly make things much simpler. In your case:

```
MockDataProvider db = new MockFileDatabase(
    "SELECT name FROM tables;\n"
  + "> name\n"
  + "> --------\n"
  + "> table_r3\n"
  + "> table_r1\n"
  + "> table_r2\n"
  + "> @rows: 3\n");

//when
List<String> nameOfTablesList = null;
try {
    nameOfTablesList = Helper.getTablesName(new MockConnection(db));
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//then
Assert.assertEquals(nameOfTablesList.size(), 3);
```

The above approach will work regardless what the `Helper.getTablesName()` method does with the passed JDBC `Connection`.

Note, I'm working for the company behind jOOQ, so this answer is biased.